# How do I change font size based on page count?

Tags: css, ms-word, macros, font-size

First of all, I'm so sorry. I'm new to all of this and trying to learn all I can. I appreciate your time and help!

I have a mail merge Word doc and I print many records at a time. The content changes depending on the field values and it can cause a page to run to 2 pages. I need to keep them at 1.

Using a Macro, how do I set the doc to change to size 11.5 if the page runs over to 2 pages and then change back to size 12 on the next record? I want to keep the other formatting (ie: bold, italic, underlining) but just change the font size.

Thank you very much!

I know there's an option on Word to "Shrink to One Page" but I'd have to manually click that for any page that runs over. If I'm printing 25+ records at once, I couldn't do that.

I've searched for macros from others but their either for text boxes or confined areas. I don't know enough coding to alter them enough to work for me.

Comment: Hi Fox, this is really not a programming question so much as a Word usage question. I think you would get better answers on the Mail Merge forum. http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/ This question may be judged to be off-topic and closed here without answers.

Answer (score 0):

**ActiveDocument.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)** gives you the page number, while **ActiveDocument.Content.Font.Size** sets the font size. So it should be as simple as:

```
Sub MyFunction()
    If ActiveDocument.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) > 1 Then
        ActiveDocument.Content.Font.Size = 11.5
    Else
        ActiveDocument.Content.Font.Size = 12
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I answered, but I agree this does not seem to be for StackOverflow, this question might be closed.

Comment: I only asked here because I saw similar, but more specific, requests answered. I've scoured mail merge options/sites and I know enough about mail merge to know this wasn't possible without coding and custom macros. Most people pointed me here. I made it a point to tag this question as MS Word.

Comment: I forgot to say thank you for your answer. And for explaining the functions. That helps with my issue and with leaning more about coding. I appreciate you for taking the time.